# Steps to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04.6 to 16.04.6 LTS or to latest 20.04 LTS (if possible)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, 20.04, lamp

I've been on 14.04 LTS for a while now and really keen to upgrade to the latest LTS version (if possible) or do I need to incrementally upgrade?

I will obviously backup my main directories and files as I'm not sure if my whole system will get wiped (hoping not) during upgrade.

Could people pls point me or guide me through the steps to carry out the upgrade as I am keen to upgrade but obviously want to make sure that is all successful and that I don't lose any of my existing data.

I also have a LAMP stack installed and hoping that this is also updated along with OS.

Comment: Ubuntu has two fully tested & supported upgrade paths, the next release (ie. 14.04 to 14.10), or from one LTS to the next LTS (ie. 14.04 to 16.04).  You can then reboot, then repeat the step as required.  You can re-install to skip releases...  The best place I'd suggest for notes/instructions are the *release notes* for the release you want to move to, ie. first jump is to 16.04, or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes  (see the *Upgrade from 14.04 or 15.10* section)

Comment: Just for the record, I decided to backup my important folders/files and just start went a fresh install of 20.04 using a iso/flash drive. This all went well compared to trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, which caused me alot of unnecessary pain and suffering.